# CodeNameone skin doesn't work

Tags: codenameone

I 've installed new version of Codename One in NetBeans IDE 8.2. But when I've press run I would see only iPhone 3g skin and I ve installed new skins but it doesn't work or doesn't shows!
Something was happened, but I don't know what happened) How I can fix it this problem?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How did you install more skins? Did you use the More menu? In the skins menu?

Comment: Yes I ve install it by more skins menu

Comment: When you open the more menu do you see the list of skins and can you click to download? Do you get errors? Are skin files installed to your home directory under `.codenameone`?